# Finding out whether A hashmap's interger values contains (val >= 25)

Tags: java, hashmap, boolean

So I have a `HashMap` whose values I'm iterating through in a `for` loop. Inside the `for` loop I'm using an `if` statement to find out whether the map contains a value of 25 or higher. But I'm having trouble finding the right syntax to say that in Java. My code looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < podMap.size(); i++)
{
    Integer j = 25;

    if(podMap.values().contains(j>=25)) // this doesn't work,
                                        // but it's essentially what I want.
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just iterate over the values directly:

```
for (Integer v : podMap.values()) {
    if (v >= 25) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Or, in Java 8, you can use `anyMatch()`:

```
return podMap.values().stream().anyMatch(v -> v >= 25);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 supports lambda expressions:

```
podMap.values().stream().anyMatch(v -> v >= 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your not actually iterating on your map...You probably want something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < podMap.size(); i++)
{
    if(podMap.get(i)>=25))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: You can't iterate a `Map` like this because `Map.get()` expects a key, not an index.

Comment: @MickMnemonic actually from his question it looks like the key is an integer otherwise why would you loop at `map.size()` so actually you can iterate over a map like this if the key is an integer...